# LUA script: Nested loop inserts only last item

Tags: arrays, for-loop, datatable, lua, nested

I have two loops, a main loop and a sub-loop inside the main loop. Both loops populate the same table (and sub-table). But for some reason the sub-loop only stores the last added item in the nested table.

For instance, main group 1 has sub-groups stored as 1-9:

*printTable(data[1][subItems][1])* -- returns error (index nil value)

*printTable(data[1][subItems][9])* -- dumps table to console

If I break the sub-loop after one iteration then *data[1][subItems][1]* contains data

```
for i=startId, endId, 10 do

  items = loadItems(i)
  data[i] = {['items'] = items}

    for x=i+1, i+10-1 do
      subItems = loadItems(x)
      print('adding items to sub-group: '..x..' for main group: '..i)
      data[i]['subItems'] = {}
      data[i]['subItems'][x] = {['items'] = subItems}
    end

  end

end
```

Since I'm printing some debug info inside the sub-loop, I know that, the code is being executed. And I know that loadItems(x) is getting the data on each iteration, because if i dump the loadItems(x) to console in the sub-loop, all is there on each iteration.

What is this wizardry?

Answer (score 1):

Silly me, how could I miss it!

The answer is of course to move the *data[i][subItems] = {}* outside the sub-loop:

```
for i=startId, endId, 10 do

  items = loadItems(i)
  data[i] = {['items'] = items}

    data[i]['subItems'] = {} <----------------------------------------------
    for x=i+1, i+10-1 do
      subItems = loadItems(x)
      print('adding items to sub-group: '..x..' for main group: '..i)
      data[i]['subItems'][x] = {['items'] = subItems}
    end

  end

end
```